# How to retrieve the view clicked on when ListFragment.onListItemClick() is fired?

Tags: android, listview

Is there a way to retrieve the view which was pressed on when

```
ListFragment.onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id)
```

is pressed?

For example I want to know which `imageView` was pressed.

Both `listView` and `view` contain a reference to the `listview`.

Comment: do you mean each row has an image, and you want to know which image is clicked?

Comment: Yes each row has many views in their layout, so I want to know which view has been pressed

Comment: You can only get the row that was clicked (= View view). If this row contains multiple Views, onListItemClick can't help you to know which View was clicked.

Comment: I was afraid of that... Thanks

Comment: @user1026605 just try to use my suggestion...i have created some complex listviews, with the answer i told you :)

Comment: I want the whole row to react to the action, therefore I don't want to listen to every view clicks. I just wanted to know how to retrieve this information from the onListItemClick() callback. But it looks like it's not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

You achive this in your listview's `adapter` class.

You should have a `holder` with (ex : `imageView`) inside your adapter. Set the `holder.imageView` `onClickListener`inside your `getView` method. If you have multiple `imageView`, you just need to add the `onClickListener` for each one of them, so the adapter will know which one is clicked.

You can access the `imageView's` position in the list (in other words - which row is clicked) by using the `position` variable from `getView` first parameter.

Comment: No I don't want to do that because then onListItemClick() won't be called anymore. I want to retrieve which view was pressed from onListItemClick() listener

Comment: I see. Sorry i dont know any alternative. If you want to use my method, you just need to move the code from onListItemClick to the adapter, via convertView.onClickListener (the 2nd param of getview).